# Sources about nocturnal emission on Yom Kippur

Tags: yom-kippur

I have heard that having  a nocturnal emission on Yom Kippur night is a bad siman for the whole year but I cannot find much on the topic...

Does anyone have sources on what this can mean?

Comment: It stems from the talmud,but many later authorities note that was in their times,but nowadays ,there is nothing to be worried about, check Shulchan Aruch Harav and Kovetz halachos

Answer (score 3):

See footnote 23 and sources referenced herein:

[image]

Comment: It's always better to explain the answer in the body of the post itself rather than just including an image.

Comment: Why?  All I’d be doing is copying the text without having read the sources referenced.  It seemed easier and more honest to just post what I had read.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the topic in the gemara discussed at the very end of [Yoma (88a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.88a.11?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi)

> תני תנא קמיה דרב נחמן הרואה קרי ביום הכפורים עונותיו מחולין לו והתניא
>   עונותיו סדורין מאי סדורין סדורין לימחל
>
> § Apropos the halakhot of immersion for one who has had a seminal
>   emission on Yom Kippur, the Gemara relates: A tanna taught a baraita
>   before Rav Naḥman: With regard to one who sees an emission of semen on
>   Yom Kippur, his sins are forgiven. The Gemara asks: But wasn’t it
>   taught in a baraita: His sins are arranged before him? The Gemara
>   answers: What is the meaning of arranged? They are arranged to be
>   forgiven.
>
> תנא דבי רבי ישמעאל הרואה קרי ביום הכפורים ידאג כל השנה כולה ואם עלתה
>   לו שנה מובטח לו שהוא בן העולם הבא אמר רב נחמן בר יצחק תדע שכל העולם
>   כולו רעב והוא שבע כי אתא רב דימי אמר מפיש חיי סגי ומסגי
>
> The school of Rabbi Yishmael taught: One who sees an emission of semen
>   on Yom Kippur should worry the whole year that perhaps he was given a
>   sign that he and his fast were rejected. But if he survives the year,
>   he can be assured that his good deeds protected him and ensured for
>   him a share in the World-to-Come. Rav Naḥman bar Yitzḥak said: Know
>   that it is so, as the whole world is hungry due to refraining from
>   conjugal relations, and he is satiated since he emitted semen and his
>   lust was subdued. Since the issue was involuntary and not intentional,
>   it is a sign that he has merited divine compassion. When Rav Dimi came
>   from Eretz Yisrael to Babylonia he said: Seeing semen on Yom Kippur is
>   a sign that one will live a long life, grow, and raise others. An
>   allusion to that is the verse: “That he might see his seed and prolong
>   his days” (Isaiah 53:10).

Additionally, the [Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.88a.10?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.615.2&lang2=bi) (615:2) writes

> הרואה קרי בליל יום הכפורים ידאג כל השנה ואם עלתה לו שנה מובטח לו שהוא
>   בן העולם הבא - One who sees a nocturnal emission should worry the
>   entire year, and if he lives through the year then he can be confident
>   he is a ben Olam Haba.

Answer (score 0):

The Shulchan Aruch Harav 615:2 writes that one who's sees Keri should be nervous throughout the year,because maybe his tefillos were not answered, and if he lives through the year then it proves he had many merits to protect him:

הָרוֹאֶה קֶרִי בְּלֵיל  יוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים – יִדְאַג כָּל הַשָּׁנָה, שֶׁמָּא לֹא קִבְּלוּ תַּעֲנִיתוֹ  וְהִשְׂבִּיעוּהוּ בְּמַה שֶּׁבְּיָדָם לְהַשְׂבִּיעוֹ, כְּעֶבֶד שֶׁבָּא לִמְזֹג כּוֹס לְרַבּוֹ וְשׁוֹפֵךְ לוֹ רַבּוֹ הַקִּיתוֹן (פֵּרוּשׁ קִיתוֹן שֶׁל מַיִם  שֶׁמִּמֶּנָּה מוֹזֵג הַכּוֹס שֶׁל יַיִן) עַל פָּנָיו, כְּלוֹמַר אִי אֶפְשִׁי בְּשִׁמּוּשְׁךָ, וְאִם עָלְתָה לוֹ שָׁנָה – מֻבְטָח לוֹ שֶׁהוּא בֶּן עוֹלָם הַבָּא,שֶׁבְּוַדַּאי יֵשׁ לוֹ זְכֻיּוֹת הַרְבֵּה שֶׁהֵגֵנּוּ עָלָיו, וְהוּא יַאֲרִיךְ יָמִים, שֶׁכָּךְ הַסִּימָן "יִרְאֶה זֶרַע – יַאֲרִיךְ יָמִים":כ

However ,in the footnotes to this halacha, it brings the Tzemech Tezedek who explains that this is talking about very great people who's minds are void of impure thoughts.  See Kovetz Halchos (Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky) which explains that for an average person one should not be worried . He brings many sources .

ראה שו"ת צמח צדק או"ח סי' קיא בשם רבנו (שהאמור כאן הוא 
לאנשים גדולים מאד שמצד הרהורי לבם רחוקים מזה מאד